# Windows 7 startup repair failed, but now Windows is running correctly. What happened?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

Today when I turned my PC on, Windows told me that there is a problem and the recommended thing to do is a repair. I selected that option and I chose Startup Repair tool, after the first run it restarted my PC and again it came to the Startup Repair, this moment it said, can't solve the solution and it should send results to the Microsoft. Anyway, next time Windows came up easily, so my question is: "Did it really repair my windows while it said the repairing was not successful?”

I also saw [Frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Startup-Repair-frequently-asked-questions) for Startup repair. But it doesn't explain in detail.

I don't know I'm confused.

Comment: Startup repair is usually a series of checks and repairs, it may have fixed one problem but failed on the next, but did repair it good enough to boot, I would not worry, it did what it was supposed to do, get you booting into Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

It does not mean that your computer will crash.
When it freezes/crashes, it tries to scan the error report and tries to find a solution by using MS error database online, when it can't find any solution,your computer goes on running.I have seen this error lots of times and it goes on well.So do not worry.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you're saying but this problem occurred after a Visual Studio Ultimate update. Therefore I thought some of windows Startup files might get damaged and the Windows cannot run, after that with the Startup repair results, there would be some mistakes in the files. Anyway thanks for share your experience.